# FHW oil basedboard radiators are hot even when t-stats turned off. Sediment in pipes?

Tags: water-circulating-heating

I moved into a condo a few months ago.  It has a forced hot water oil heating system.  First floor is one heating zone; second floor is another; boiler is in basement.  T-stats are manual/mercury dial.

Soon after moving in we noticed second floor radiators were hot even though t-stat was turned all the way down.  My friend, who works in HVAC, suggested sediment might be in pipes, preventing valves from closing.  He suggested banging on the pipes to correct this.  This appears to have worked for a couple months.  But the problem has returned and it appears to now also affect 1st floor radiators.

Suggestions for what to try now?  Thanks!!!

Comment: I love examples of when "banging on it" actually helps, even if it was just temporary.